# Linked to database in ipython, no data

Tags: sql, pandas, ipython

First, my apologizes if this is too simplistic or off topic. I have tried any number of resources and am to the point of just asking.

Problem: I have a .db (created in sqlite) file on my hard drive that I am trying to connect to and run some simply queries. I am able to connect to the table (emails), and get the headers returned, but no data from the cells. Code below.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users...emails.db')

df = pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM emails",conn)
df


Out[28]:id  sender_name sender_email    recipient_name  recipient_email subject conversation_topic  message_date    message_id  text_body
```

Anyone have any ideas on what I am missing? 
thanks!

Comment: Apologizes if this is too simplistic, but could the emails table be empty? Use your sqlite manager/console to find out.

Comment: Definitely not empty. I see all the data in the sqlite db browser, and the file is 17gbs. That is what I thought as well, but definitely has data. :-/

Comment: Some suggestions: try different extension: '..emails.sqlite' or 'emails.sqlite3' OR use `pandas.read_sql('SELECT * FROM emails, conn)` without query or `pandas.read_sql_table('emails', conn)`.

Comment: What does `type(df)` give? (it does not look like a dataframe) Further, what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: By the way, 17gbs is an incredibly large database to be imported into a data frame. Pandas tend to struggle even with large csv files where chunks have to be read iteratively. Do you have enough RAM to handle this load? Do you need all columns? Any filtering can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your db file is too big for Pandas?

Try inserting a `WHERE` clause into your sql statement to just grab a few records and see if that works.